# Need help in filtering the records in lightning application

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I am very new to salesforce Lightning application development. I am looking for some help from you in creating a functionality in the lightning app. I have loaded all the accounts into the lightning component and I need to filter the records using the BillingCity by clicking the Billing city name. Once the billing city is clicked, all the accounts related to that city should be displayed and the filter can be cleared by clicking on the clear filter image (here I used a black circle) which loads all the records except the particular criteria.

Please help !!!

## Aura Application

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <c:AccountMainScreen/>
</aura:application>
```

## AccountMainScreen.cmp

```
<aura:component controller="AccountController">
    <aura:attribute name="allaccounts" type="List" description="All Products" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.fillAccount}"/>
    <div class="container">
        <div style="font-weight: bold;">Filter by Billing City</div><br/>
        <div>Bangalore</div><br/>
        <div>Mountain View</div><br/>
        <div>Singapore</div><br/>
        <div>
        <div style="background-color: #7f7e8a;height: 20px;"></div>    
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.allaccounts}" var="account">
            <article class="slds-card">
            <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid">
             <header class="slds-media slds-media--center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
              <div class="slds-media__body slds-truncate">
        <h2>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-text-link--reset">
            <span class="slds-text-heading--small">{!account.Name}</span>
          </a>
        </h2>
      </div>
    </header>
  </div>
  <div class="slds-card__body">{!account.BillingCity}</div>

</article>
        </aura:iteration>
        </div>

    </div>   

</aura:component>
```

## AccountController.apxc

```
public class AccountController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Account> getAllAccounts()
    {

        List<Account> lstacc=[select Name,BillingCity from Account where BillingCity != null];
        return lstacc;

    }

}
```

## AccountMainScreenController.js

```
 ({     fillAccount : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.getAccountsfromSF(component, event)  } })
```

## AccountMainScreenHelper.js

```
({
    getAccountsfromSF : function(component, event) {

        var action = component.get('c.getAllAccounts');
        action.setCallback(this,function(actionResult){
        component.set('v.allaccounts', actionResult.getReturnValue());           
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);    

    }
})
```

[image: Lightning App Main Page]

Answer (score 1):

This will help to you

**Component:**

```
    <aura:iteration var="a" items="{!v.AccountList}" indexVar="indx">
        <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="pick" text="{!a.BillingCity}" name="{!indx}" label="{!a.BillingCity}" change="{!c.selectoptionvalue}"/>
    </aura:iteration>

<aura:iteration items="{!v.selectedvalues}" var="account">
    <article class="slds-card">
        <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid">
            <header class="slds-media slds-media--center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
                <div class="slds-media__body slds-truncate">
                    <h2>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-text-link--reset">
                            <span class="slds-text-heading--small">{!account.Name}</span>
                        </a>
                    </h2>
                </div>
            </header>
        </div>
        <div class="slds-card__body">{!account.BillingCity}</div>

    </article>
</aura:iteration>
```

**Controller:**

```
({

initmethod : function(component,event,helper){
    var action = component.get("c.getAccountList");
    action.setCallback(this,function(a){
        var state=a.getState();
        if(state == "SUCCESS"){
            component.set("v.AccountList",a.getReturnValue());
        }

    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},

selectoptionvalue :function(component,event,helper){
    var temp=component.get("v.selectedvalues");
    var selectedcity=component.get("v.SelectedCity");
    var accountdetails = component.get("v.AccountList");
     temp = [];//empty when while changing Picklist value
    if(event.getSource().get("v.value")){
        selectedcity.push({'ids':event.getSource().get("v.name"),'name':event.getSource().get("v.text"),'value':event.getSource().get("v.value")});
    }
    if(event.getSource().get("v.value") == false){
        for(var j=0;j<selectedcity.length;j++){
            if(selectedcity[j].ids == event.getSource().get("v.name")){
                var index = j;
            }
        }
         selectedcity.splice(index,1);
     }
      component.set("v.SelectedCity",selectedcity);      
    var accountdetails = component.get("v.AccountList");        
    for(var i=0;i<accountdetails.length;i++){
        for(var k=0;k<selectedcity.length;k++){
            if(accountdetails[i].BillingCity == selectedcity[k].name){
                temp.push(accountdetails[i]);
            }
        }
    }

    component.set("v.selectedvalues",temp);
}
```

})

**Apex:**

```
public class valuesget {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Account> getAccountList(){
        return [Select Id,Name,BillingCity  From Account where BillingCity != null];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vignesh. I am trying to build the filter functionality somewhat similar to this website . https://www.costadelmar.com/shop/sunglasses. Let me know if this kind of functionality can be achieved or not.

Comment: Yup, we can Do it.I just Gave a example As you asked **Once the billing city is clicked, all the accounts related to that city should be displayed**( I used picklist to select the Billing city name).let mre know Is these your scenario I  gave example.bellow
If you have Three choices ex: ->Chennai
                                               ->Banglore
                                               ->mountain
If you select all ,related fields belong to three cities want to display
If you unselect Banglore  Filtering done  by(chennai and mountain).Is it right

Comment: In your example, you are displaying all the accounts of a particular billing city but I am looking for a solution where multiple cities can be selected and all the account names of the selected cities should be displayed on the screen.

Comment: yup I got it I modify the code as your requirement wait

Comment: Rajesh this code might help to you